# Python: Separate Gtk thread unresponsive while main thread is working

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, gtk

I'm helping a github project for a cryptocurrency coin ticker that sits in the ubuntu notification area. It uses libappindicator and gtk to display, and glib to set timeouts.

The full code is here: https://github.com/bluppfisk/coinprice-indicator/tree/separate_tickers

Now, because of limitations with the Appindicator, I decided to run a new appindicator instance from the main thread for each ticker I show, with a separate appindicator icon as the app's 'main menu'.

Then, because `Gtk.main()` process blocks my script from doing anything else, I cannot first load the main menu and then each ticker as the data comes in. So I decided to run `Gtk.main()` in a separate thread.

This works mostly fine: the main icon loads first and then the main thread fires off its HTTP requests for ticker information, and one appindicator after the other appears with the right data in the notification area.

However, whenever the main thread is starting these HTTP connections, I cannot trigger the About Dialog created with `Gtk.AboutDialog()`. Also, the close button on the About Dialog as well as any other UI elements only react when the HTTP requests have completed.

I thought that running `Gtk.main()` in a separate thread would run it simultaneously?

Here's the interesting bit of code:

```
import threading, gi
import from gi.repository Gtk, GdkPixbuf, GObject

try:
    from gi.repository import AppIndicator3 as AppIndicator
except ImportError:
    from gi.repository import AppIndicator

Class Coin(Object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.gui_ready = threading.Event()
        self.start_main()
        self.add_indicator()
        self.add_indicator()
        Gtk.main()

    def start_main()
        self.main_item = AppIndicator.Indicator.new(appname, icon, AppIndicator.IndicatorCategory.APPLICATION_STATUS)
        self.main_item.set_status(AppIndicator.IndicatorStatus.ACTIVE)
        self.main_item.set_label("", "")
        self.main_item.set_menu(self._menu())
        self.gui_thread = threading.Thread(target=self.start_gui_thread)
        self.gui_thread.start()
        self.gui_ready.wait()

    def start_gui_thread(self):
        GObject.threads_init()
        self.gui_ready.set()
        Gtk.main()

    def _menu(self):
        menu = Gtk.Menu()
        self.about_item = Gtk.MenuItem("About")
        self.about_item.connect("activate", self._about)

    def _about(self, widget):
        about = Gtk.AboutDialog()
        # rest of code to run dialog, incl. buttons to close

    def add_indicator(self, settings=None):
        indicator = Indicator(self, len(self.instances), self.config, settings)
        self.instances.append(indicator)
```

Comment: Gtk should be your main thread, then you just do blocking work like http in a  thread and return to the main thread with `GLib.idle_add()`.

Comment: Do you mean using `GLib.idle_add(callable)` to start my UI indicators? For some reason, it still seems to block. Or do you mean using idle_add() without callable argument?

Comment: Your main application runs in a main loop, this blocks until the end of your application. Within that mainloop you can spawn worker threads (these **cannot** touch the UI) and when they are done with work you call `idle_add()` to return the main thread.

Comment: Unfortunately, the indicators do need to update the UI, filling it with new data as it comes in. This works fine at the moment, but the threads seem to be blocking. And I'm unsure how to use `idle_add()`.

Maybe UI programming isn't for me :)